# Entry Form in Meteor

Tags: jquery, forms, collections, meteor, publishing

I currently have an entry form and my last question is the Subject Tag. What I'm trying to do is if a user selects one or more of the categories below, the accompanying post will be displayed on tabs corresponding to that Subject.

[image]

For example, I have one Collection shown below named Posts and would like to essentially sort them based on the users input of Science, Math, Business, etc.

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');
```

and this is the code that I'm using to extract the data input from the form into usable information...

```
Template.postCreate.events({
'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Sucessfull!");

    var post = {
        class: $(event.target).find('[name=class]').val(),
        purpose: $(event.target).find('[name=purpose]').val(),
        time: $(event.target).find('[name=time]').val(),
        date: $(event.target).find('[name=date]').val(),
        place: $(event.target).find('[name=place]').val(),
        room: $(event.target).find('[name=room]').val(),
        details: $(event.target).find('[name=details]').val(),

        tag: $(event.target).find('[name=tag]').val() {


            }
        }
    }
```

How would I take input from the radio button in my form and publish it in the corresponding tabs in my navbar?

Comment: Clarify you question. What tab you are  talking about?

Comment: I have tabs for Home, Science, Math, Business, etc in my navigation bar. Each tab has its own post feed. My question is how can I get the users input from the checkbox to display on my multiple feeds (i.e. the Science feed will contain only Science related posts, the Math feed will contain only Math related posts, and the Home feed will contain all posts).